# Dismiss activity started from service and return to previously open app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a service that is started by a BroadcastReceiver triggered by an alarm. In this context, none of my app's activities are running and the main activity doesn't even have to be started.

From the service I start an activity set with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and that is working fine. The problem is in the behavior of how this activity is dismissed by the user after I call finish();

1. If I'm using another app when this activity is brought to focus, once I dismiss it, Android takes me to my app's main activity instead of taking me back to the app I was using previously;
2. If my phone's screen is off and the activity is shown (I have a wake lock), calling finish() doesn't really "finish" it. I mean, the activity is sent to the background so I can see the lock screen but the activity is still listed in the list of open apps. I can only really close it by swiping it away.

Are those normal behaviors in this case? Does anyone know how to avoid them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how I declared my activity in the manifest. In order to get this properly, I had to include android:excludeFromRecents="true" to my  declaration. I also removed my main activity from the intent-filter section.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, you might have to show some code as in How are you starting that particular activity and what code is executed on finish. It might be that the home activity starts before your intended activity is actually brought to the front. When you close the desired activity, it again comes to the front.

For the second question, it is normal behavior. It does happen for all apps with me. Not sure if its the case for only new versions of Android. Not sure why would you want to avoid them.

Comment: Hi, thanks. My code is a standard call to a notification with setFullScreenIntent pointing to an intent initialized with the flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION. There is nothing extraordinary there. And I'm calling notify() from a service as I mentioned in the original post. My app might not even be running when this is taking place so what could be launching the home activity?